# KivyMD mdlabel add_widget() and self.texture_size

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Using KivyMD and I would like to add MDLabel using add_widget() I would like to set the size to

```
width = self.texture_size[0] 
height = self.texture_size[1]
```

Here is the rest of my code for the label.

```
            card.add_widget(MDLabel(
                text="Name: " + r[1],
                bold= True,
                size_hint=(None, None),
                halign="center",
                pos_hint={"center_y": .8}
            ))
```

How can I set width and height to self of the object I am creating as self in this case will refer to the main app?

Change the size of a MDLabel from a python code rather than a kv file.

Comment: What version of kivymd are you using ?

Comment: Version: 1.0.0.dev0

Comment: You can use prop. `adaptive_size`. If that does [not work](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/1096) properly, try binding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What do you mean by try binding?

Comment: Did you try with `adaptive_size`?

Comment: Yes that, does the trick thank you. But it turns out it only helped me uncover my bigger problem, I need to learn how to add a MDRelativeLayout to the MDCard that i am creating in python code and not the KV file.

Comment: This Post got me the rest of the way there Thanks for the help. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346311/how-to-position-async-images-inside-kivymds-mdcard-in-py-file)